# How do you use a variable in a regex replace statement

Tags: regex, replace

I'm trying to use both a variable and a backreference in a string replacement

```
akId =  "Hello"

$content -replace '(?<one>one)=(?<two>.*)','$1=${$akId}'
```

variable doesn't get the value. Using double quotes doesn't work for the back reference.

How is this done?

Comment: No, it works well with double quotes, just make sure you escape the backtick where it is a literal char, ``"`$1=${$akId}"``

Comment: Is this PowerShell?

Comment: Thanks, the backtick works. (Powershell)